# Let $a,b,n$ be any integers, show that: $x^{n}\cdot{y^{n}}=(xy)^{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, exponentiation

I know the rule of adding exponents while multiplying same integers: $$x^{a}\cdot{x^{b}}=x^{a+b}$$ but that doesn't seem to help, in this case. 
An elementary proof would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$ here?

Comment: And $(xy)^a=?$.

Comment: We also know the rule $x^ay^a=(xy)^a$. Doesn't matter if p is prime

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  It sounds like you need to prove $(xy)^{p-1}=x^{p-1}y^{p -1}$ which is trivial and has nothing to do with p being prime.

Comment: Can you show me an example? @EugenCovaci

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake while calculating! Yes it has nothing to do with prime, it could be any integer. I'm editing the question. @fleablood

Comment: The question I beg to ask is: How do you define "elementary proof? What are your constraints of $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Show by induction on $n$ that if $x,y$ are any integers you have
$$x^ny^n=(xy)^n$$

The inductive step boils down to $y^nx=xy^n$.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm I'm kinda noob when it comes to "proof by induction", if you please could do it for me that would be great. Thanks @N. S.

Comment: @user18724 Just write what $P(1)$ is and then in $P(n+1)$ just use that $$(xy)^{n+1}=(xy)^n(xy)$$ Use $P(n)$ and you are done.

Comment: You also need the associative and commutative properties.

Answer (score 2):

$$(xy)^n= \underbrace { (xy)\cdots (xy)}_{n\text{(xy)'s}} = \underbrace {x\cdots x}_{n\text{x's}} \times \underbrace {y\cdots y}_{n\text{y's}}=x^ny^n$$

This is easy enough, so induction is not necessary.

Comment: yes I think I can help you there, since I messed up my proof :(

Comment: Is it any better?

Comment: There's nothing wrong, you got it right

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, of course sorry

Comment: Mine is clearly wrong so I will delete it

Comment: It looks fine to me, what did you want improved?

Comment: the underbrace will only be as long as the code above it

Comment: How about now, is it okay?

Comment: I'm trying to get an overbrace for the top part, but can't figure it out

Comment: okay good job (+1)

Comment: a hard birth indeed :)

Comment: Thanks @Peter that was very useful and that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

expand the RHS

```
     (xy)^n = (xy)(xy)(xy)...(xy)

                  n times
```

Now since x,y integers, they commute, change order

```
         = x.x.x.x...y.y.y.y..

            n times   n times
```

Hence

```
         = x^n.y^n
```